# Piezoelectricity and conservation of energy

Tags: energy-conservation, piezoelectric

This is how I understand piezoelectricity: The molecules of a material have electric dipole moments. When a sample of the material is under mechanical stress, the molecules "slide"/"turn" and become oriented in such a way that the electric moments point the same way (and as more pressure is applied, more moments are oriented and thus electric field strength and voltage across the sample is increased).

Now, if we apply the stress and just leave it there, should we not have a continuous voltage across the sample, and a continuous current flowing? But if we don't need to lift or move the applied stress in any way, we seem to get continuous current and therefore power from nothing. Why doesn't this break conservation of energy?

Comment: Just because you have voltage does not mean you have current...

Comment: @JonCuster If I connect a resistor across the crystal, there is voltage and a path for the current. How is there no current?

Comment: How much current do you get? Of course you can get some. Put not forever - you only get the net surface charge at best.

Comment: @JonCuster I still don't understand. What is "net surface charge"? I'm just thinking there is an electric field across the crystal and there are free charge carriers. The free charge carriers are forced through the crystal by the electric field and into the external circuit (such as a resistor) and more charge is being attracted from the other side of the crystal and a current flows.

Comment: Well, there are no free carriers in a piezoelectric. Physical deformation of a unit cell results in mechanical separation of charge to create an electric field. But, that charge cannot move. Each unit cell acts like a small capacitor. Over a chunk of piezo material, one builds up a lot of small capacitors in series, generating a large voltage. Now, place a wire between top and bottom - all you can do is move enough charge to counteract the mechanical charge imbalance. Then you are done - nothing else happens. No charge flows out of the material.

Comment: @JonCuster Okay, so there isn't actually a current through the crystal in the same way there isn't actually a current through a capacitor? The "current" is actually just induced by a changing electric field? The crystal as a *whole* is kind of like a capacitor?

Comment: Pretty much. You have physically displaced fixed charge.